# No está funcionado la navegación por pestañas de bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap

Buenas, estoy usando el gestor de plantillas twig para renderizar una página que muestra una navegación por pestañas. He probado con muchos códigos pero ninguno parece funcionar, y creo que la razón por la que no funciona es, porque viendo el inspector, al parecer los enlaces no agarran los eventos del jquery. No sé que está mal: he probado todos los códigos aparte y funcionan perfectamente. Éste es el último que probé (sacado de w3school):

```
{% block tabs %}

<div class="container">
<h2>Dynamic Tabs with jQuery</h2>

<p>Click on the Tabs to display the active and previous tab.</p>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
     <div id="first" class="tab-pane fade in active">
         <h3>HOME</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
     </div>
     <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
         <h3>Menu 1</h3>
         <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
     </div>
     <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
         <h3>Menu 2</h3>
         <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
     </div>
     <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
         <h3>Menu 3</h3>
         <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
<hr>
<p class="act"><b>Active Tab</b>: <span></span></p>
<p class="prev"><b>Previous Tab</b>: <span></span></p>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
    $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
        var x = $(event.target).text();         // active tab
        var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text();  // previous tab
        console.log(x);
        console.log('y');

        $(".act span").text(x);
        $(".prev span").text(y);
    });
});
</script>

{% endblock tabs %}
```

Les agradecería cualquier ayuda que me pudieran brindar!

Comment: Puedes mostar tus script tags?

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que no funciona? He copiado el código que compartes a este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pbuoex6/) y las pestañas funcionan sin problemas. Si no va nada, no me extrañaría que te faltase incluir alguna biblioteca en tu código.

Comment: Se ha cumplido más de un mes sin comentario por parte del autor de la pregunta, que se debería hacer?

Comment: @CarlosGomez podrías pasarnos como incluyes tus scripts ?